# Add Events To Dynamically added Buttons in Winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, mouseevent, mousehover

I had Added Button Controls dynamically in window form,now i want to add different event to every button control.
 Here is my code of adding button dynamically from database.

```
private void GetButtonDynamically()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        conn.Open();
        using (conn)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select MenuName from tblMainMenu",conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                    Button mybutton = new Button();
                    mybutton.Location = new Point(x, y + 54);
                    y += 54;
                    mybutton.Height = 44;
                    mybutton.Width = 231;

                    mybutton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                    mybutton.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                    mybutton.Text = reader["MenuName"].ToString();
                    mybutton.Name = reader["MenuName"].ToString();
                    mybutton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);

                    Controls.Add(mybutton);
                    mybutton.Click+= new EventHandler(mybutton_Click);

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem i am facing is it generate same Event for every button that is created dynamically, and i want different method for every button

Here Is Click Event

```
 private void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button is Clicked");
    }
```

Comment: What's the signature of the `mybutton_Click` method?

Comment: What would be differences between different method for every button?

Comment: `mybutton.MouseHover += mybutton_Click` should work, no need to wrap it in a delegate

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Different Event mean For example i want one button to Show Button is clicked and on another button i want to show Button is Hovered.

Comment: And how do you decided which button to click and which button to Hover?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah that is what i want to do how to assign these event to button

Comment: `mybutton.Click+= new EventHandler(mybutton_Click);` this is how you assign Click event to the button. It's not clear what exact issue you are facing.

Comment: You should know for which button you want to handle `Click` event and for which button you want to handle `Hover` event. Then attach those event handler to those buttons. Also keep in mind, `sender` parameter of the event handler contains the button which its event has occurred and you can get the button this way: `var b  = (Button)sender;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "AccessibleName" for your button while creating it. In your case inside your while loop and get the accessible name in button click event and apply a switch case or loop to differentiate it. sample code

```
int x = 10; int y = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Button mybutton = new Button();
            mybutton.Location = new Point(x, y + 54);
            y += 54;
            mybutton.Height = 44;
            mybutton.Width = 231;
            mybutton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            mybutton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            mybutton.Text = i + "MenuName".ToString();
            mybutton.Name = i + "MenuName".ToString();
            mybutton.AccessibleName = i.ToString();
            mybutton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);
            Controls.Add(mybutton);
            mybutton.Click += new EventHandler(mybutton_Click);
        }
```

In Button click modify like this

```
        private void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Button cb = (Button)sender;
          string strName = cb.AccessibleName;
          switch (strName)
          {
            case "1":
                MessageBox.Show("Button 1 is Clicked");
                break;
            case "2":
                MessageBox.Show("Button 2 is Clicked");
                break;
            case "3":
                MessageBox.Show("Button 3 is Clicked");
                break;
            default:
                break;
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int y = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {

                    Button mybutton = new Button();
                    mybutton.Location = new Point(0, y + 10);
                    y += 54;
                    mybutton.Height = 44;
                    mybutton.Width = 231;

                    mybutton.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                    mybutton.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                    mybutton.Text = "a "+i.ToString();
                    mybutton.Name = "b" + i.ToString();
                    mybutton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);

                    switch (i)// define your condition
                    {
                        case 1:
                            mybutton.Click += new EventHandler(mybutton_Click);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            mybutton.Click += new EventHandler(mybutton_1_Click);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    Controls.Add(mybutton);
                }
            }
            private void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button 1 is Clicked");
            }
            private void mybutton_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button 2 is Clicked");
            }
```

Comment: Excuse me,I didn't find out your question correctly